# sort post category listing

Tags: categories

By default, when a post with multiple category (or category with sub category) is created, wordpress listed those categories in alphabetical order in the admin post listing page.

[image: **example**]

Is there any way to change the way this sorting is done?

```
$cat=get_the_category();
echo $cat[0]->cat_name;
```

This is why I need this. I want the parent category to be the first item in the array.

Comment: got another way to solve this.

Comment: Consider answering your own question in order to help future visitors who may have the same question.